# How to change Symfony2 default structure?

Tags: php, symfony

May I change the default Symfony2 structure to fit my needs?
I like the follow structure, but don't know how to get it to working..

```
core/ <- Symfony2 core files
app/ <- All applications
app/Acme/ <- Application for Acme enterprise (with all bundles..)
app/clientone.com/ <- Application for Client One enterprise (with all bundles..)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside symfony2 distribution there are 4 main directories:

- app (there are customisations to your app)
- vendors (symfony and other libraries)
- src (your source code which may or may not to be application specific, 
  there could be bundle ClientoneBundle which is specific to only this application,
  but also could be a bundle reused among your applications,- such as UserBundle)
- web (http document root)

So if you have several applications you could keep vendors separately. And each of your application may contain three directories like: 
 - apps/acme/app
 - apps/acme/src
 - apps/acme/web
 - apps/clientone/app
 - apps/clientone/src
 - apps/clientone/web
 - some/where/else/in/filesystem/vendor

To implement such setup is very easy,- all you have to do is edit your autoload.php (which resides in app dir), just replace everywhere `__DIR__.'/../vendor` to `__DIR__.'/../vendor`,
in other words, tell symfony2 that you moved vendors somewhere else.

(I just renamed app directory in your setup to apps - to be not confused with app directory, inside each of your application)

Comment: The vendo directory have the Symfony core files, plus 3rd part libs?

Comment: Another question, may I share bundles between applications?

Comment: Yes, vendors are Symfony + some other libraries like Doctrine, Swiftmailer and others. And bundles can be shared, where each bundle is placed you may set also in autoload.php, see registerNamespaceFallbacks .